# SPList.GetItems(view) returns an exception when attempting to get item title

Tags: c#, sharepoint

When I try:

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
{
    SPList list = web.Lists["Blah"];
    SPView view = web.GetViewFromUrl("http://foo.com/Lists/Blah/View%20Name.aspx");

    foreach (SPListItem item in list.GetItems(view))
    {
        writer.write(item.Title);
    }
}
```

item.Title gets me an ArgumentException.

But when I just use

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
     writer.write(item.Title);
}
```

It works just fine.

What is happening here?  What can I do to get the title of the list item when passing in a view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your view definition. Is "Title" one of the fields included in the view definition?

In your first code snippet you're filtering items from your list based on the view. In the second snippet, you're accessing the items directly from the list without filtering.

As an aside: looping on list.Items is a bad idea. Unfortunately the implementation of this property in SharePoint causes it to retrieve items from the database for each iteration of the loop. This code is preferred and equivalent:

```
SPListItemCollection listItems = list.Items;
foreach (SPListItem item in listItems)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Title is included, and thanks for the pointer on looping on list.items.

Even if I use the AllItems view, I still get the exception.

Comment: Try modifiying the AllItems view and ticking all columns in the list named "Title". This includes all columns that have names with parentheses after them like "Title (link to edit item)".

Comment: Cool! Now the reason for this is: the "Title" column added by default in a view is actually a computed column based on the actual underlying Title column in the list definition. Views use computed columns to render HTML formatting around the value of another column. So in your view you were selecting the computed column based (called LinkTitle) and this is why Title wasn't found in the list item collection. (I hope that makes some sort of sense!)

Answer (score 1):

It's sharepooint bug connecting with GetItems by SPView object. When you will retrieve view from list, for example: list.Views["View Name"] ViewFields contains only two fields(Title, LinkTitle) and the SPQuery for retrieved view is empty. If you wanna to filter your list items or get fields via SPQuery class.

Also you wanna to get working state the GetItems(spView) method. You can reset HttpContext and then try to get spView.

For example:

```
    private SPListItemCollection GetItemsByEventType()
    {
        HttpContextHelper.ResetCurrent();
        SPList list;
        try
        {
            SPWeb web = Context.Site.OpenWeb(Context.Web.ID);
            try
            {
                list = web.Lists[ListName];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                list = web.GetListFromUrl(ListName);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ListViewName))
            {
                SPView view = list.Views.Cast<SPView>()
                    .Where(t => t.Title == ListViewName)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                return list.GetItems(view);
            }
        } finally
        {
            HttpContextHelper.RestoreCurrent();
        }

        return list.Items;
    }

    protected new SPContext Context
    {
        get { return SPContext.GetContext(base.Context); }
    }

public class HttpContextHelper
{
    #region Fields

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static HttpContext _current;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public static void ResetCurrent()
    {
        if (_current != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        _current = HttpContext.Current;
        HttpContext.Current = null;
    }

    public static void RestoreCurrent()
    {
        HttpContext.Current = _current;
        _current = null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```